# Android device to detect display is on or off using the hdmi cable

Tags: android, hdmi

I am creating a app where videos are played in T.v by connecting the android device to T.v through HDMI cable.I want detect if T.V is turned off using the HDMI cable.I also tried a method mentioned in this link but its not working.
[How to check the HDMI device connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644665/how-to-check-the-hdmi-device-connection-status-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data file from the location `/sys/class/display/display0.hdmi/connect`.If the data in the file is 0 hdmi is not connected if its 1 its connected.

Try this method:

```
try {
  File file = new File("/sys/class/display/display0.hdmi/connect")
  InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
  byte[] re = new byte[32768];
  int read = 0;
  while ((read = in.read(re, 0, 32768)) != -1) {
      String string="Empty";
      string = new String(re, 0, read);
      Log.v("String_whilecondition","string="+string);
      result = string;

  }
    in.close(); 
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I think it depends on the device, I don't see a /sys/class/display on my device.

Comment: yes,it depends on the manufactures but most of the devices will have this files.