# Read raw streams from HDMI inputs in android box

Tags: android

I am writing an app for android boxes (not Android TV), that have HDMI input port. How do I read raw video stream from HDMI input and display it in android videoView ?

The Android boxes I am using have Amlogic processors. It uses API level 19 (Android 4.4) and above.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's not straightforward. You would need a modified kernel to detect and interface with the HDMI device. To get the HDMI input data from the device itself you'll need to write NDK code. Then after modifying the input data into an [appropriate format which is compatible](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html), such as encoding it to H264, you'll be able to feed it into a VideoView.

[See this thread for someone who did something similar, taking HDMI input on a Nexus 7](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1841759)

[How to detect an HDMI connection on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25437174/5063104)

Comment: If I got hdmi-cec enabled from vendor, how does the android read the datas passed through hdmi? I've gone through the the android source docs but couldn't find my answer.