# In Android, how can my code determine if an HDMI-connected monitor is powered-on?

Tags: android, hardware, detection, monitor, hdmi

Using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644665/how-to-check-the-hdmi-device-connection-status-in-android) I was able to determine whether the Android device I'm writing for (a "Ugoos" appliance) thinks a monitor is attached.  The code works, reasonably well.

However, if the monitor is powered-off, the code still reports that the HDMI device is connected.  I've tried everything I can think of, but can't find code to determine whether the monitor is turned off or not.

I even did a "before and after" ls -lR of the /proc and /sys directories and compared them, to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: I did a google search, it seems not possible. Have you found a solution for it? Would you mind to share your solution?