# Detect if HDMI service is UP on android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, exoplayer, hdmi, exoplayer2.x

We have a problem with HDMI service. Our Android TV app are set as default on STB. When you launch STB it doesnt show you launcher, it shows you out App immediately with playing HLS video stream. For playing video we are using [Exo Player](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) version 2.6.1 with [Exo Media wrapper](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia) version 4.1.0. Time by time we investigate black screen when STB wakes up after sleep - power On by DPAD. Playlist what we get in this cases is working and switching channel to another works well. This issue is produced commonly at the same users.

Here what we get from log when screen is black (URL_TEST is our playlist request):

```
09-06 19:21:40.018 I/PowerManagerService(  369): Waking up from sleep...
09-06 19:21:40.018 I/WindowManager(  369): No lock screen!
09-06 19:21:40.038 I/AudioHardwareALSA(  104): AudioHardwareALSA::setParameters() screen_state=on
09-06 19:21:40.038 I/qtaguid (  369): Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10056) res=-1 errno=1
09-06 19:21:40.038 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  369): setKernelCountSet(10056, 1) failed with errno -1
09-06 19:21:40.078 D/LightsService(  369): Excessive delay setting light: 54ms
09-06 19:21:41.018 W/SurfaceFlinger(  101): Timed out waiting for hw vsync; faking it
09-06 19:21:41.158 W/OkHttp  (  682): previous digest authentication with same nonce failed, returning null
09-06 19:21:41.158 D/OkHttp  (  682): Cached authentication expired. Sending a new request.
09-06 19:21:42.018 W/SurfaceFlinger(  101): Timed out waiting for hw vsync; faking it
09-06 19:21:42.098 D/DAKARMainActivity(  682): URL_TEST getUri: http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXXX/XLIVE/0431233...8355920521/26/3/stream.m3u8
09-06 19:21:43.098 W/SurfaceFlinger(  101): Timed out waiting for hw vsync; faking it
09-06 19:21:43.428 W/DisplayD(   97): iface id HDMI screen is 0
09-06 19:21:43.428 D/Displaymanager(   97): [setHDMIEnable] display 0
09-06 19:21:43.428 D/Displaymanager(   97): [operateIfaceMode] property 0 iface 4 type 1 mode 1280x720p-60
09-06 19:21:43.428 D/Displaymanager(   97): [operateIfaceEnable] property 0 iface 4 operate 1 value 1
09-06 19:21:43.438 W/Displaymanager(   97): interface 4 not support led
09-06 19:21:43.648 I/ActivityManager(  369): Config changes=1400 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_LU ldltr sw720dp w1280dp h672dp 160dpi lrg long land -touch -keyb/v/h dpad/v s.8}
09-06 19:21:43.658 D/RemoteControlManager(  369): BroadcastReceiver:android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
```

What we got from log when everything is OK and video is playing after start on the same device (URL_TEST is our playlist request):

```
09-05 19:21:58.507 I/PowerManagerService(  369): Waking up from sleep...
09-05 19:21:58.517 I/WindowManager(  369): No lock screen!
09-05 19:21:58.527 D/SurfaceFlinger(  102): Screen acquired, type=0 flinger=0x40691318
09-05 19:21:58.537 I/AudioHardwareALSA(  105): AudioHardwareALSA::setParameters() screen_state=on
09-05 19:21:58.537 I/qtaguid (  369): Failed write_ctrl(s 1 10056) res=-1 errno=1
09-05 19:21:58.537 W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(  369): setKernelCountSet(10056, 1) failed with errno -1
09-05 19:21:58.577 W/DisplayD(   98): iface id HDMI screen is 0
09-05 19:21:58.577 D/Displaymanager(   98): [setHDMIEnable] display 0
09-05 19:21:58.577 D/Displaymanager(   98): [operateIfaceMode] property 0 iface 4 type 1 mode 1280x720p-60
09-05 19:21:58.577 D/Displaymanager(   98): [operateIfaceEnable] property 0 iface 4 operate 1 value 1
09-05 19:21:58.577 W/Displaymanager(   98): interface 4 not support led
09-05 19:21:58.587 D/LightsService(  369): Excessive delay setting light: 59ms
09-05 19:21:58.797 D/RemoteControlManager(  369): BroadcastReceiver:android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
09-05 19:21:58.797 D/Environment(  369): screen raw size:1280,720
09-05 19:21:58.797 I/ActivityManager(  369): Config changes=1400 {1.0 ?mcc?mnc en_LU ldltr sw720dp w1280dp h672dp 160dpi lrg long land -touch -keyb/v/h dpad/v s.9}
09-05 19:21:58.947 W/OkHttp  (  681): previous digest authentication with same nonce failed, returning null
09-05 19:21:58.947 D/OkHttp  (  681): Cached authentication expired. Sending a new request.
09-05 19:21:59.077 I/Displaymanager(   98): updatesinkaudioinfo: 0x408de140
09-05 19:21:59.077 I/Displaymanager(   98): BUF: AC3,LPCM,
09-05 19:21:59.077 I/Displaymanager(   98): 
09-05 19:21:59.077 W/DisplayD(   98): Send msg Iface added HDMI
09-05 19:21:59.137 D/DAKARMainActivity(  681): URL_TEST getUri: http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:13888/XLIVE/4086274310...086993824321/26/3/stream.m3u8
09-05 19:21:59.417 I/OMXClient(  681): Using client-side OMX mux.
09-05 19:21:59.417 I/        (  681): new RKOMXPlugin
09-05 19:21:59.427 D/ACodec  (  681): MEDIA_MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC sampleRate 48000 wifidisplay_flag 0 info 6c5bbe78
09-05 19:21:59.427 E/OMXNodeInstance(  681): OMX_GetExtensionIndex failed
```

We noticed from log when we have black screen we have this Displaymanager (HDMI) messages after video request:

```
 09-06 19:21:42.098 D/DAKARMainActivity(  682): URL_TEST getUri: http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXXX/XLIVE/0431233...8355920521/26/3/stream.m3u8
09-06 19:21:43.098 W/SurfaceFlinger(  101): Timed out waiting for hw vsync; faking it
09-06 19:21:43.428 W/DisplayD(   97): iface id HDMI screen is 0
09-06 19:21:43.428 D/Displaymanager(   97): [setHDMIEnable] display 0
09-06 19:21:43.428 D/Displaymanager(   97): [operateIfaceMode] property 0 iface 4 type 1 mode 1280x720p-60
09-06 19:21:43.428 D/Displaymanager(   97): [operateIfaceEnable] property 0 iface 4 operate 1 value 1
09-06 19:21:43.438 W/Displaymanager(   97): interface 4 not support led
```

When everything is OK it goes vice versa - see logs above.

Our assumption that black screen could be caused by HDMI service which arent UP at the moment when we request video stream.

We have tried to detect HDMI connection by all of this methods (when HDMI is connected/up then we start video playing) - [How to check the HDMI device connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644665/how-to-check-the-hdmi-device-connection-status-in-android/), but nothing helps.

Android version 17.

Any ideas what could cause this problem?

UPD1:

Attach the [same issue github discussion](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4817)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem resolved with ExoPlayer update to 2.8.4 and ExoMedia to 4.2.3