# Permission denied while reading a system file on Android

Tags: android, hdmi

I am trying to add "HDMI connection" check in my app.

I referred to [How to check the HDMI device connection status in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644665/how-to-check-the-hdmi-device-connection-status-in-android) and decided to add the checks to read **/sys/devices/virtual/switch/hdmi/state** or if not, **/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state** files.

But I am getting:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

with "Permission denied". Do we need to request some permissions for this kind of access?

Thanks,
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across the same problem.

1. resolve permissions problem

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

READ should be enough but if you grand Write works the same.

2. resolve runtime permmision problem - if you work with API 23+ you have to ask permission on runtime.
3. Root device - I had to root device to access **sys/class/switch/***